# Drive API Not Syncing PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API in my web application. I completely removed the "Getting Started" file and added a couple folders about 5 days ago to the service accounts Google Drive that I am connecting to. But instead of the API returning current data (two folders), it returns old data (the "Getting Started.pdf" file).

Why is the API doing this? How can I use PHP to fix it? I prefer using the SDK functions over the URLs, just so you know.

The code that isn't working is

```
$pageToken = null;
do {
  $response2 = $service->files->listFiles(array(
    //'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    'spaces' => 'drive',
    'pageToken' => $pageToken,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  ));
  foreach ($response2->files as $file2) {
      echo "Found file: " . $file2->name . " " . $file2->id;
  }
} while ($pageToken != null);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using for this? Also, include the error message if you got any? For the meantime, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) of Google Drive API to verify if you do your command properly.

Comment: @KENdi There. I added the code that I am using for this. I don't get an error message, I just don't get any files returned besides the Getting Started.pdf file. The code is taken directly from the documentation quick start guide except I changed the print commands to echo to make it work in a browser.